# In Kivy How do i get a variable from another screen displayed in another in kv language

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I am trying to modify the pong game from the kivy docs.

I have made a "Game End" screen that the app goes to after a winner is declared, in there i want a label that displays the score of the winner, with the method used below i get completely different output in the label,

Can someone explain please how i should achieve that ? Thank you!!

**The relevant code is at the bottom of both i am just including the whole code in case the issue is somewhere else.**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix import label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label





class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    def On_Win(self):
        p1 =self.Game.player_1.score



class MenuWindow(Screen):
    pass 

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_y= NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_x= NumericProperty(0)

    velocity=ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x,velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(self.velocity) +self.pos



class PongPad(Widget):

    score=NumericProperty(0)

    def Check_bounce(self,ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball)   :
            vx,vy= ball.velocity
            bounced= Vector(-1* vx, vy )
            speedup= abs(((ball.velocity_x *0.1) -(ball.center_y - self.center_y)) *0.002) 
            vel = bounced *  (speedup +1.1)
            offset=(((ball.center_y - self.center_y)/2) - (ball.velocity_x /2)) *0.1
            if (ball.center_y - self.center_y) > 0:
                ball.velocity=vel.x,vel.y
                ball.velocity_y= 2
            else:
                ball.velocity= vel.x,vel.y
                ball.velocity_y= -2


class Game(Screen):



    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player_2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    win1=NumericProperty(0)
    win2=NumericProperty(0)
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)

    def Winner(self):
        Winner=""
        if self.player_1.score==2:
            if self.manager.current != "WinGame":
                self.manager.current = "WinGame"
                Winner = "P1 with",str(self.player_1.score) 
        if self.player_2.score == 2:
            if self.manager.current !="WinGame":
                self.manager.current = "WinGame"
                Winner = "P2 with",str(self.player_2.score)

    def TEST(self):#TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
        Winner=""
        if self.player_1.score>=2:
            Winner = "P1 with",str(self.player_1.score)
        print("1")
        print(Winner)
        return Winner
    def serve_ball(self,vel=(4,0)):
        print("234Served")
        self.ball.velocity= vel
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.player_1.center_y=self.center_y
        self.player_2.center_y=self.center_y


    def Check_Top_Bottom(self):
        #Check bottom collion
        if self.ball.y <0:
            self.ball.velocity_y= abs(self.ball.velocity_y)

        #Check top colision
        if self.ball.y+50> self.height:
            self.ball.velocity_y = -abs(self.ball.velocity_y)

    def Check_if_score(self):#Score
        if self.ball.x >self.width:
            self.player_1.score +=1
            self.win1 +=1
            self.serve_ball()
        if self.ball.x+50 <0:
            self.player_2.score += 1
            self.win2 +=1
            self.serve_ball()

    def update(self,dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.Check_Top_Bottom()
        self.Check_if_score()
        self.player_1.Check_bounce(self.ball)
        self.player_2.Check_bounce(self.ball)
        self.Winner()
        #print("from Update: ",self.Get_Score())


    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        if touch.x > self.width/2:
            self.player_2.center_y = touch.y
        else:
            self.player_1.center_y= touch.y



class WinGameScreen(Screen):
    def Get_Win(self):
        screen_manager = self.manager
        game = screen_manager.get_screen('Game')
        a= game.TEST()
        return a


kv= Builder.load_file("myMenu.kv")


class myMenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv




if __name__ == "__main__":
    myMenuApp().run()
```

And here is the kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    MenuWindow:
    Game:
    WinGameScreen:

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "Menu"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.75}
            text:"Play"
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "Game"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.7}
            text:"Settings"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.65}
            text:"High Score"
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"y":0.6}
            text:"Quit"

<PongBall>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size




<PongPad>
    size_hint: None, None
    size:25,150
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<Game>:
    name:"Game"
    ball: Pong_ball
    player_1: Player1
    player_2: Player2


    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x -5,0
            size: 15,root.height

    PongPad:
        id: Player2
        pos:root.width-25,root.center_y-75

    PongPad:
        id: Player1
        pos:0,root.center_y-75

    PongBall:
        id: Pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center



        FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:str(root.player_1.score)
            top:root.top -1
            x:root.width -100

        Label:
            text:"Player 2:"
            top: root.top-1
            x:root.width - 135

        Label:
            text: str(root.player_2.score)
            top: root.top -1
            x: root.x+25


        Label
            text: "Player 1:"
            top:root.top-1
            x:root.x -10

<WinGameScreen>:
    name:"WinGame"

    Label:
        id: Final_score
        text: str(root.Get_Win)
        y:0.2
```

Comment: I don't see `Game End Screen` in code. And I don't see in which `Label` you want to display finall score. As I remeber in `kv` you can use `app` instead of `root` to get access to main class - and later you may try to use `ids` to get access to object/subclass in main class. Eventually you can try to use `.parent` or many `.parent.parent` to get access to previous element - i.e. in `Screen` you can try to use it to acces `ScreenManage` and later use `.ids` to access othe `Screen` and elements in this screen.

Comment: frankly, I don't know why you don't set value in label directly in `def Get_Win(self):`. BTW `root.Get_Win` should give reference to function - if you want to get value from function then you should use it with `()` to run function - `root.Get_Win()`

Comment: BTW: if you want to assign text to variable then you should format string - `"P1 with " + str(self.player_1.score)` - or use `f-string`  `f"P1 with {self.player_1.score}"` - because  using `"P1 with ",str(self.player_1.score)` you create tuples and `print()` will display it with `( , )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `kv`, the line:

```
    text: str(root.Get_Win)
```

is setting the text of the `Label` to the string version of the `Get_Win()` method when the `kv` is loaded. It is not running the `Get_Win()` method. You can just delete that line.

Since you switch to the `WinGameScreen` when the game is over, you can define an `on_enter()` method for the `WinGameScreen` which will get run whenever that `Screen` is entered:

```
class WinGameScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        screen_manager = self.manager
        game = screen_manager.get_screen('Game')
        a= game.TEST()
        self.ids.Final_score.text = str(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom sensei for the code now runs